# JavaFX TreeTableView: text not showing

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to build a TreeTextView. My FXML has the following declaration:

```
<TreeTableView fx:id="tree">
    <columns>
    <TreeTableColumn fx:id="c1" prefWidth="131.0" text="NAME" />text="DETAILS" />
    </columns>
</TreeTableView>
```

My Controller is doing this:

```
@FXML
private TreeTableView<Factor> tree;
@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<Factor, String> c1;

@FXML
private void someMethod() {
    // create root
    Factor hr = new Factor(null, "HR");
    TreeItem<Factor> root = new TreeItem<Factor>(hr);

    // creta sub 
    Factor spec = new Factor(hr, "Spec");
    TreeItem<Factor> specTI = new TreeItem<>(spec);

    // spec to HR
    root.getChildren().add(specTI);

    c1.setCellValueFactory((
                    TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Factor, String> param) -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(
                    param.getValue().getValue().getName()));

    // set root
    tree.setRoot(root);
}
```

Factor has a constructor `Factor(Factor f, String name)` and a method `String getNome()` returning its name.

With this code, I don't see any text in the TreeTableView, even though I see the arrow to expand the structure (which is actually there).

What's wrong?

Comment: When is someMethod() invoked?

Comment: When I trigger an event. It does get invoked for sure.

Comment: maybe you wrote this one wrong  : `<TreeTableColumn fx:id="c1" prefWidth="131.0" text="NAME" />text="DETAILS" />`